# Google’s SMS retriever API is working fine without the <#> prefix. Why?

Tags: android, google-api, sms-retriever-api

according to the Google’s SMS retriever API, the SMS message should start with the <#> prefix, but it's working well for me without it (on multiple phones and system versions). Has anyone ever encountered that and knows why it's possible?

https://android.jlelse.eu/googles-sms-retriever-api-6540eb3c8e9c

Comment: What API are you using exatly? Show us some code.

Comment: Are you using SMS retreiver API or SMS UserConsent API

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh SMS retreiver API.

Answer (score 2):

Google has removed the prefix from their API documentation.
But I don't know when it was changed.

Here is their latest example of the message content. (https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#1_construct_a_verification_message)

```
Your ExampleApp code is: 123ABC78


FA+9qCX9VSu
```

Comment: It would've been nice for them to tell exactly when the prefix requisite was removed.